# Replace all single quotes in a string query

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, mysql-workbench

I have a file with SQL queries similar to this:

```
INSERT INTO Bank (bankCode, swiftCode, bankName, country, countryCode, locationCode, 
address, city) 
VALUES ('MIDL', 'MIDLGB2102N', 'Hsbc Bank Plc', 'United Kingdom', 'GB',
'21', '', 'Bishop's Stortford');
```

I have to replace all single quotes inside a string literal in order to be able to execute the query.

Can someone provide a regular expression in order to achieve that?

For example the above query should be:

```
INSERT INTO Bank (bankCode, swiftCode, bankName, country, countryCode,
locationCode, 
address, city) 
VALUES ('MIDL', 'MIDLGB2102N', 'Hsbc Bank Plc', 'United Kingdom', 'GB',
'21', '', 'Bishop''s Stortford');
```

Replace **'Bishop's Stortford'** with **'Bishop''s Stortford'** . Replace **'** with **''**

Comment: Do you control the way file content is generated? If yes, how do you generate them?

Comment: I generated the file. But I don't want to generate it again. I just want to replace them with 'Replace'

Answer (score 0):

You have PDO::quote function in PHP for this purpose. Check this link: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php

---

If you want a pattrn for regex replace: `/(\(|\s)'([\w ']*)'(,|\))/`
Or in PHP: `preg_replace("/(\(|\s)'([\w ']*)'(,|\))/", '$1"$2"$3', $line);`

Comment: I just want to use file and generated queries to insert to DB through workbench

Comment: So how you will process that file? Through PHP script?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach would likely be something akin to:

`/[^,(]\s*'\s*[^,)]/`

This would match all <kbd>'</kbd> characters which are not preceded by or following a comma or a paren (only other valid MySQL characters). I included a search for spaces because those are also possible valid characters.

That would certainly *match* everything. I'm not terribly familiar with how MySQL Workbench parses replaces in regular expressions, so I cannot be much assistance there.

Answer (score 0):

To import via MySQL Workbench do the following:

1. Go to excel and have your data the way you need to reflect your table structure
2. In excel Save As -> CSV
3. In workbench right click on table and choose 'Select Rows'
4. In result set, click icon 'Import Records from External File'
5. Select your CSV
6. Import